# bcp queryout dreadful performance

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, bcp

I'm using SQL Server 2008 R2. I have a stored procedure that runs `bcp` via `xp_command` shell. On my laptop with a copy of the database, a job with 50000 records is almost instant and `bcp` performance is 71K rows per sec.

I run exactly the same stored procedure on the server and it takes 1h 51 minutes and `bcp` performance is 7 rows per sec (so 10,000x slower). The query that selects the data runs in under a second on the server BTW. This happened last week and we restarted the SQL Server instance and it ran pretty quick again on server. After about 5 days, the performance got real slow again, but restarting SQL instance didn't help.

My command is:

```
bcp "exec DBNAME.dbo.SPNAME 224,1 "  
    queryout "\\Server\path\OUTPUT\11111.txt" -c -t\t -Usa -P"PASSWORD" -SSQLSERVER
```

If I run activity monitor, I see my stored procedure process and it says RUNNABLE.

The server is on a VM with 4 cores and 28GB RAM.

If I run the same `bcp` command from a dos shell, I get same.

I'm at a loss where to look now. Anyone got any suggestions?

TIA

Mark

Comment: What kind of performance do you get if you do not write it to a UNC share (\\Server\path\OUTPUT\11111.txt) but you put it directly on the C:\ drive of the SQL server?  That will tell you if it is network or not.

Comment: This is actually a local drive. I did try with the drive letter instead. Got same perfromance

Comment: The logical place to look is indexes.  This could happen if you have an index(es) on your local PC that the server does not have.

Comment: Indexes are identical. As I mentioned in my post, the database is a copy from the server and the query that selects the data runs in under a second on the server.

Answer (score 0):

To answer the question of "where to look" and because the task you are trying to complete involves distributed resources (I'm assuming here because you are using UNC paths)... you have to look into differences between the environments, which when comparing execution between Server and laptop... is just about everything.

Storage (and available storage)
CPU (and available cpu)
Network (and available bandwidth)
Memory (and available memory)
SQL Server version/updates
Maintenance schedules (of which the laptop will likely have none)
concurrent activity (of which the laptop will likely have none)

The data you seem to have addressed. You can confirm that the data/database objects are the same? This is a restored database you are working with on the laptop (restored from the server?) or you've manually inspected tables and indexes if not a restore from the server?

If not restored, could the laptop have less data?

To troubleshoot, you'll also need much more than activity monitor. You'll need performance monitor.

This is from some time ago (not sure why things like this dont expire on here, but oh well).